# Internal Server Error (500)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, routes, laravel-5.6

Having issue with this

```
if(attributeName == 'id'){
    var id = dataValue;

    $("#discard").click(function(){
        alert(id);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'deleteob/' + id
        });

    });
}
```

I have this route in web.php

```
Route::get('/deleteob/{id}', 'RequestsController@deleteOBRequest');
```

Then this is my controller

```
  public function deleteOBRequest($id){

    $masterIds = OBMaster::findOrFail($id);
    $detailIds =  OBRequest::where('details_id', $masterIds->id);

    $masterIds->destroy();
    $detailIds->destroy();

    return redirect('OB_ViewDetails');
  }
```

My problem is there's is a internal server error (500). i'm new in laravel. 
Hope someone can give me some ideas.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Please check your code here and see whether there is some data management error: $masterIds = OBMaster::findOrFail($id); $detailIds = OBRequest::where('details_id', $masterIds->id);

Comment: Please check your error.log and post the error message.

Comment: @Thomas.lin . Thanks you for ur comment. I change the destroy() to delete() and it successfully deleted.

Comment: good to hear that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use

```
$masterIds->delete();
$detailIds->delete();
```

instead of

```
$masterIds->destroy();
$detailIds->destroy();
```